# Unix : how to tar only N first files of each folder?

Tags: tar

I have a folder containing 2Gb of images, with sub-folders several levels deep.

I'd like to archive only `N` files of each (sub) folder in a tar file. I tried to use `find` then `tail` then `tar` but couldn't manage to get it to work. Here is what I tried (assuming `N = 10`):

```
find . | tail -n 10 | tar -czvf backup.tar.gz
```

… which outputs this error:

```
Cannot stat: File name too long
```

What's wrong here? thinking of it - even if it works I think it will tar only the first 10 files of all folders, not the 10 files of **each** folder.

How can I get `N` files of each folder? (No file order needed )

Comment: +0.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Do you wish to have the first 10 files, sorted numerically, alphabetically,  by date or does the order not matter?

Comment: @unforgettableid : I have to work on a web site locally, but there are 9Gb of images on server and I don't need all of them !

Comment: @Sam: Ah OK. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

If your `pax` supports the `-0` option, with `zsh`:

```
print -rN dir/**/*(D/e:'reply=($REPLY/*(ND^/[1,10]))':) |
  pax -w0 | xz > file.tar.xz
```

It includes the first 10 non-directory files of each directory in the list sorted by file name. You can choose a different sorting order by adding the `om` glob qualifier (order by modification time, `Om` to reverse the order), `oL` (order by length), `non` (sort by name but numerically)...

If you don't have the standard `pax` command, or it doesn't support `-0` but you have the GNU `tar` command, you can do:

```
print -rN -- dir/**/*(D/e:'reply=($REPLY/*(ND^/[1,10]))':) |
  tar --null -T - -cjf file.tar.xz
```

If you can't use `zsh`, but have access to `bash` (the shell of the GNU project), you could do:

```
find dir -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -O dotglob -c '
  for dir do
    set -- "$dir/*"; n=0
    for file do
      if [ ! -d "$file" ] || [ -L "$file" ]; then
        printf "%s\0" "$file"
        (( n++ < 10 )) || break
      fi
    done
  done' bash {} + | pax -0w | xz > file.tar.xz
```

That would be significantly less efficient though.

Comment: print -rN -- dir/**/*(D/e:'reply=($REPLY/*(ND^/[1,10]))':)  -> Get error message : -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @user1916171, It seems you missed the _with zsh_ and _If you can't use zsh_ parts of that answer. `bash` is a different shell, the shell of the GNU project which is much more limited compared to `zsh`. See the end of the answer for a solution that would work with `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the output of `find` is flat, you don't really know which files belong to the same directories without looking at the paths. The alternative is to use multiple `find`s (one per folder), without having to look at the paths. This is what I did. In order to tar up to a maximum of 10 files of each subfolder, use something like this:

```
for dir in $(find . -type d); do
  find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "\"%p\"\n" | tail -10
done | xargs tar cvfz backup.tar.gz
```

This recursively finds all directories in the current folder. For each directory, it finds up to 10 files in *exactly* that folder (`-maxdepth 1`). Once the entire loop is finished, the `tar` command is executed on all files that were output by the loop. I also accounted for directory and folder names with spaces by quoting `$dir` and having `find` print each filename within quotes using the `-printf` option.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your master directory is `/tmp/dir` from which you want to archive only N (e.g N=10) files of each (sub) folder under it to a `backup.tar.gz` file.

Example `tree` for `/tmp/dir`:

```
dir/                                                                                                                                                                                                           
├── one
│   ├── one10.txt
│   ├── one11.txt
│   ├── one1.txt
│   ├── one2.txt
│   ├── one3.txt
│   ├── one4.txt
│   ├── one5.txt
│   ├── one6.txt
│   ├── one7.txt
│   ├── one8.txt
│   ├── one9.txt
│   └── one_deep
│       ├── one_deep1
│       ├── one_deep10
│       ├── one_deep11
│       ├── one_deep2
│       ├── one_deep3
│       ├── one_deep4
│       ├── one_deep5
│       ├── one_deep6
│       ├── one_deep7
│       ├── one_deep8
│       └── one_deep9
├── three
│   ├── three10.txt
│   ├── three11.txt
│   ├── three1.txt
│   ├── three2.txt
│   ├── three3.txt
│   ├── three4.txt
│   ├── three5.txt
│   ├── three6.txt
│   ├── three7.txt
│   ├── three8.txt
│   ├── three9.txt
│   └── three_deep
│       ├── three_deep1
│       ├── three_deep10
│       ├── three_deep11
│       ├── three_deep2
│       ├── three_deep3
│       ├── three_deep4
│       ├── three_deep5
│       ├── three_deep6
│       ├── three_deep7
│       ├── three_deep8
│       └── three_deep9
```

#### Code:

```
cd /tmp; for i in `find dir/* -type d`; do find $i -maxdepth 1 -type f | tail -n 10 | xargs -I file tar -rf backup.tar file; done; gzip backup.tar
```

This will create a `backup.tar.gz` with 10 files of each sub folder from under `/tmp/dir`.

Comment: If for some reason `cd /tmp` fails, you'll run that command in the wrong directory. You should always check the exit status of `cd`: `cd /tmp && for...`

Comment: `find dir/* -type d` means you won't be processing the hidden directories in the current directory, but will be processing them in subdirectories. Either use `find dir -type d` or if you don't want the files in the current directory: `find dir/. ! -name . -type d` or `find dir ! -path dir -type d`.

Comment: Using `\`find...\`` means invoking the split+glob operator (split only in zsh). Here  you don't want the glob part, and you want to split on newline only (though newline is a valid character in a file name, so that approach is flawed anyway, and you should use `find`'s `-exec` instead).

Comment: Leaving that `$i` unquoted also means invoking the split+glob operator which doesn't make sense here. Use `find "$i"`

Comment: Note that even with `-I`, `xargs` still treats quote and backslash characters specially in its input. It also means running one `tar` command per line which is not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in ./*/
do
    cd "$d"
    tar -rvf ../backup.tar $(ls | tail -10)
    cd ..
done
gzip backup.tar
```

other variant

```
find * -prune -type d -exec bash -c 'printf "%s\n" $0/* | tail -10' {} \; |
tar czvf backup.tar.gz -T -
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash on the directory name, and only emit the filename if the hash value count is below the threshold. E.g.

```
find . -depth -type f \
| perl -MFile::Spec -nle '(undef,$d,$f)=File::Spec->splitpath($_); print if $seen{$d}++ < 3' \
| tar ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (or most easy to understand) way is to use xargs with the `-N max-args` option.

Keep in mind, that your input always needs to be something, which does not require a commandline, so `echo *.*` will work as input, where `ls *.*` does not (too long ls commandline)

find should be fine, as its argument is only the path, not a list of files.

Answer (score 0):

OP asked this [over in Stackoverflow too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034207/unix-how-to-tar-only-n-first-files-of-each-folder). Here's the answer I offered there.

The selection and order of files in this answer is determined by the order out of `find`, so "first" isn't well-defined here. This may also depend on GNU Awk 4.1.0.

```
find . -type f |
awk -v N=10 -F / 'match($0, /.*\//, m) && a[m[0]]++ < N' |
xargs -r -d '\n' tar -rvf /tmp/backup.tar

gzip /tmp/backup.tar
```

Comments:

1. use `find . -type f` to ensure that files have a leading directory-name prefix, so the next step can work
2. the `awk` command tracks such leading directory names, and emits full path names until N (10, here) files with the same leading directory have been emitted (perhaps simpler `awk` use - splitting info pattern and program - might be more portable)
3. use `xargs` to invoke `tar` - we're gathering regular file names, and they need to be arguments to that archiving command
4. `xargs` may invoke `tar` more than once, so we'll append (-r option) to a plain archive, then compress it after it's all written

Also, you may not want to write a backup file into the current directory, since you're scanning that - that's why this suggestion writes into /tmp.